# Using ViewPager caches Fragments after screen rotation?

Tags: android, android-widget

I initially create my fragments inside the Activity onCreate(). Than I go about creating the ViewPager and setting up the adapter.  I keep a global reference to the fragments so I can update them as needed.  Also, these fragments are accessed by the adapter.

My issue is that I notice once the screen is rotated the Fragments are recreated but the ViewPager still contains the original fragments created...??

How am I supposed to handle the life-cycle of my fragment?  I need to be able to call directly to the fragment from the activity. Is a singleton for a fragment a good idea? Or just a memory leaker?

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
...
...
        // set up cards
        mFrag1 = new Frag1();
        mFrag1.setOnActionEventListener(mOnActionEvents);

        mFrag2 = new Frag2();
        mFrag3 = new Frag3();

        mFragPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        mFragAdapter = new FragAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mFragPager.setAdapter(mCardAdapter);
        mFragPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mOnCardChange);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Global instances and static fragments are definitely a bad idea. Unless you call `setRetainInstance()` on a fragment, it will be serialized to a Bundle and recreated when an the parent activity is re-created (on screen rotate, etc.). That will, of course, produce new fragment instances, and your old references will be invalid. You should get references to fragments via `FragmentManager.findFragmentById/Tag()` as needed and definitely not store those in static variables.

You may need to show more of our code, but as long as you create the fragments in `onCreate()`  the references should be valid for the lifetime of the activity. Check the compatibility library sample code for more on using fragments with `ViewPager`.

Comment: How do you set a fragment id? I'm using `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById` but I don't know how to set a fragment id. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134926/getsupportfragmentmanager-getfragment-without-tag-or-id

Comment: Look at the `ViewPagerAdapter` source, it sets tags automatically, you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: Ok, so how can I know these tags?

Comment: Get the fragment instance from your adapter and call `getTag()` on it.