# getSupportFragmentManager getFragment without tag or id

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm developing an Android 3.1 Tablet application.

I'm using ViewPager and fragments on one activity. My problem is that I don't know how to set an ID or Tag to fragments.

**Activity**

```
public class FillEReportFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    ...

    /**
     * View Pager to manage form parts.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    /**
     * Page Adapter to handle fragments.
     */
    private FillEReportFragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        Log.v("FillEReportFragmentActivity", "onCreate");

        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.fill_ereport_paged);

        // Recoge los argumentos que le llegan de la actividad padre.
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            qapId = extras.getLong(BundleKeys.qapIdKey);
            orderId = extras.getLong(BundleKeys.orderIdKey);
            eReportId = extras.getLong(BundleKeys.eReportIdKey);
        }

        // Cargamos el E-Report o creamos uno nuevo. Además se recuperan los
        // artículos de la orden actual.
        LoadEReportAsyncTask task = new LoadEReportAsyncTask(this);
        task.execute(Long.toString(this.qapId));

        // Establezco los fragmentos (o partes del form) que se mostrarán en el
        // View Pager.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new FillEReportFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        // Muestro en la parte inferior unos círculos para indicar donde me
        // encuentro dentro del E-Report.
        CirclePageIndicator mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

        // Creo unos tabs para poder navegar más facilmente a través de las
        // partes del E-Report.
        TabPageIndicator titleIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.tabIndicator);
        titleIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

        ...
}
```

**FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
public class FillEReportFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private static final String[] TITLES = new String[] { 
        "Factory", 
        "Items" 
    };

    public FillEReportFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                return FactoryInfoFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return ItemsFragment.newInstance();

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 2; // TODO: Este número hay que cambiarlo porque serán más.
    }

    public String getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return TITLES[position];
    }
}
```

**res/values/ids.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="frag_general_info_factory"/>
    <item type="id" name="frag_general_info_items"/>
</resources>
```

**FactoryInfoFragment**

```
public class FactoryInfoFragment extends Fragment
{
    public static FactoryInfoFragment newInstance()
    {
        FactoryInfoFragment frag = new FactoryInfoFragment();

        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.v("FactoryInfoFragment", "onCreateView");

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_general_info_factory, container, false);
    view.setId(R.id.frag_general_info_factory);

        return v;
    }
}
```

**frag_general_info_factory.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*">

      <TableRow
        android:weightSum="1"> <!-- 0 -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGenInfo"
        android:layout_span="8"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/layout_title_general_information"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
      </TableRow>

      ...

</TableLayout>
```

**Here I want to get an specific fragment**

```
private class LoadEReportAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog loadingDialog;
    private EReport eReport;
    private QAP qap;

    public LoadEReportAsyncTask(Context context)
    {
        Log.v("LoadEReportAsyncTask", "constructor");
        eReport = null;
        qap = null;

        this.mContext = context;
        loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        loadingDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        loadingDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_loading_ereport));
        loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        loadingDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        Log.v("LoadEReportAsyncTask", "doInBackground");
        ...
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        Log.v("LoadEReportAsyncTask", "onPostExecute");

        FillEReportFragmentActivity parentActivity = (FillEReportFragmentActivity) mContext;
        if (result)
        {
            FactoryInfoFragment factFragment = (FactoryInfoFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_general_info_factory);
            factFragment.fillEReport(eReport, qap);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.msg_ereport_got_correct), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ItemsFragment fragment = (ItemsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_general_info_items);
            fragment.setUpArticles(orderArticles);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.msg_ereport_problem), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        loadingDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**Here:**
`(FactoryInfoFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_general_info_factory);`

I use `R.id.frag_general_info_factory` to get that fragment reference but I get a **null**.

How can I set a Tag or an Id to `FactoryInfoFragment`?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Does your code is now working? can you share the working code? Thanks.

Comment: Too bad nobody gave a proper answer to this question as I have the same problem.

Comment: I think that the proper answer is that the architecture of the solution is complicated and wrong. I've never encountered a situation where using a ViewPager, finding the right fragment was a problem, because unless the fragments are hardcoded (in which case this is trivial because you know the positions in advance), you always have access to a data source that backs your fragment adapter and therefore you can use the adapter's data source to obtain your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Fragment by using the `id` of  the View the ViewPager adds it to:

```
    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameWhichFragmentHasBeenAddedTo);
```

Your problem is finding this id. I've run through the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/compatibility/AndroidSupportV2/src/android/support/v2/view/ViewPager.java?r=3488) for `ViewPager` and it doesn't jump out, if anything I would suggest it uses itself (a `ViewGroup`) so the id you should use in this instance would be `R.id.pager`;

**NB**

You may also want to be very careful when mixing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.app.Fragment` - It means the difference between using the functionality in the support library or in the Honeycomb+ API.

i.e, if you use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`:

```
    getSupportFragmentManager();
```

else if you use `android.app.Fragment`:

```
    getFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Thank you. This is another question: if I'm using Android 3.1 with `ViewPager` and `fragments`, do I need to use `android.support.v4`?

Comment: if you are using 3.1 you shouldn't have the android-support-v4.jar in your project (AFAIK) and therefore shouldn't be using android.support.v4,

Comment: My problem is that I don't know the id of the view that I've added. How can I know that id?

Comment: But... I see that `ViewPager` is only on `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` package.

Comment: @Graeme I've updated my question with your answer but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override

```
public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position)
```

in your `FragmentPagerAdapter` to save or set the id of that container `ViewGroup` and then call `super`.

Then you can use that saved id on `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` to retrieve the fragment.

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried by `instantiateItem` is never called. I see `onCreateView` and `onResume` on my log, but I don't see any call to `instantiateItem`.

Comment: I'm using a ViewPager and I don't know how to call `instantiateItem`.

Comment: @VansFannel You should override `instantiateItem` in your `FillEReportFragmentPagerAdapter`, not in your `FactoryInfoFragment`.

Comment: Sorry, I see that `instantiateItem` is executed but I have done what you said me (I've set a new Id) and I've got a null.

Comment: Is the `ViewGroup container` null when `instantiateItem` is called?

Comment: No. Container is `ViewPager` object.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I don't know if `findFragmentById()` will work properly in this case, given that there is actually more than one fragment associated with the ViewPager container.

If you look at the source code of the `FragmentPagerAdapter` you can see how it is using tags internally.  Then perhaps you override `instantiateItem()` in your custom pager adapter, copying in the code from `FragmentPagerAdapter` and adjusting it to use tags that you can also use elsewhere in your code to retrieve the fragments yourself.

For example, if your PagerAdapter implementation could be specific to this one problem, you could do something as simple as this:

```
private String getTag(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return FactoryInfoFragment.class.toString();
    case 1:
        return ItemsFragment.class.toString();
    default:
        return "unknown:" + position;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried by `instantiateItem` is never called. I see `onCreateView` and `onResume` on my log, but I don't see any call to `instantiateItem`.

Comment: hmm, maybe you have implemented it in the wrong place?  It should be a member of your `FillEReportFragmentPagerAdapter`.  It is ultimately what calls `getItem()`.  So, if `getItem` is being called, you can be sure that `instantiateItem` is being called.

Comment: `instantiateItem` is called, and then it calls `getItem`. As you can see on my `FragmentPagerAdapter` code, I create fragments on getItem so, I think, it is impossible to set an Id to a fragment it it is not created yet. Probably I'm not doing it well with my code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it looks like `findFragmentById()` and `findFragmentByTag()` won't do the job so what I would do is to store all of your `Fragments` into an `ArrayList<Fragment>` so you can access them from both your `Adapter` and the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Even I did this , but I am still concerned if this is a good practice both memory wise and performance wise?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Android's FragmentManager (via `getSupportFragmentManager()` for the `AppCompatActivity`), you normally retrieve a fragment using its tag or its ID. These are the recommended ways to do so.

However, if you don't have a tag or an ID, but you know the order in which you've added your fragments, you could theoretically retrieve them using the back stack. Still, this is generally a less reliable method and could lead to issues, especially if the back stack changes or if fragments are dynamically added/removed.

Here's how you might do it:

```java
public Fragment getFragmentByIndex(int index) {
    List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null && fragments.size() > index) {
        return fragments.get(index);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method retrieves all currently added fragments to the FragmentManager and tries to return the one at the given index.

**But be cautious!**:

1. The order of fragments in the list is not guaranteed to be stable over time. If you add, remove, or replace fragments, the order may change.
2. This approach does not account for fragments that may be in the back stack but are not currently added (e.g., if they've been popped).

It's best practice to always tag your fragments or use an ID when adding them, so you can reliably retrieve them later. If possible, modify your design to ensure you always have a tag or ID for any fragment you might need to retrieve.